# How to get Autocomplete Multi-select to work in Blazorise

Tags: c#, blazor, blazorise

Trying to get Multiple Autocomplete to work in my Blazorise Project. Want it to generally work like this [example](https://preview.blazorise.com/docs/extensions/autocomplete).

I have entered the code example given in Blazorise:

```
@page "/MultipleSelectPage"

<h3>MultipleSelect</h3>

<Autocomplete TItem="Country"
              TValue="string"
              Data="@Countries"
              TextField="@(( item ) => item.Name)"
              ValueField="@(( item ) => item.Iso)"
              Placeholder="Search..."
              Multiple
              FreeTyping
              @bind-SelectedValues="multipleSelectionData"
              @bind-SelectedTexts="multipleSelectionTexts">
</Autocomplete>

<Field Horizontal>
    <FieldBody ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is12">
        Selected Values: @string.Join(',', multipleSelectionData)
    </FieldBody>
    <FieldBody ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is12">
        Selected Texts: @string.Join(',', multipleSelectionTexts)
    </FieldBody>
</Field>

@code {
    [Inject]
    public CountryData CountryData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Country> Countries;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Countries = await CountryData.GetDataAsync();
        multipleSelectionData = new List<string>() { Countries.ElementAt( 1 ).Iso, Countries.ElementAt( 3 ).Iso };
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    List<string> multipleSelectionData;
    List<string> multipleSelectionTexts = new();
}
```

and added everything else I believe I need into the project (like CountryData.cs etc.)

Oddly, Multiple in the Autocomplete section is in red, but there is no suggestion for what to do with it, and the program compiles and runs (see below).

I have went through the other parts of the code that I added from the Blazorise example I downloaded, but for the life I me I cannot see what the issue is.

Any assistance would be greatly, greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: My first guess would be that you might not be using the version that allows that. Seems that it has been added in version 0.9.5.

Comment: I was going to reply that I was on the latest version, but you were correct, I was not! So I have update to version 1.0.5 for every Blazorise component.  But now I have just a few new errors. In _Imports my @using Blazorise.Icons.FontAwesome is red on Icons. In my _Hosts.cshtml file the href links (like to _content/Blazorise/blazorise.css are blue and say they are not found.  Same with some script src like "_content/Blazorise/blazoris.js" and a few others. I think this is just my not understanding the structure of the _Hosts.cshtml file. Can you please give me a hand on this?

Comment: How many versions did you skip? Some breaking changes may exist when updating, here's the one for 0.9.5: [Release notes](https://blazorise.com/news/release-notes/095)

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I stumbled across your example.  Try using SelectionMode instead.  Like this:

```
SelectionMode="AutocompleteSelectionMode.Multiple"
```